# Color the Events Manager small calendar every two days

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, calendar

I would like to create a different color background for every two days on this calendar. Representing:

- A-SHIFT
- B-SHIFT
- C-SHIFT

Currently if I add `style="background-color:red"` to the `<td>`tag it will color the entire calendar.

```html
<?php 

?>
<table class="em-calendar">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td><a class="em-calnav em-calnav-prev" href="<?php echo $calendar['links']['previous_url']; ?>" rel="nofollow">&lt;&lt;</a></td>
            <td class="month_name" colspan="5"><?php echo ucfirst(date_i18n(get_option('dbem_small_calendar_month_format'), $calendar['month_start'])); ?></td>
            <td><a class="em-calnav em-calnav-next" href="<?php echo $calendar['links']['next_url']; ?>" rel="nofollow">&gt;&gt;</a></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="days-names" style="background-color:#AD1010">
            <td><?php echo implode('</td><td>',$calendar['row_headers']); ?></td>
            
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <?php
            $cal_count = count($calendar['cells']);
            $col_count = $count = 1; //this counts columns in the $calendar_array['cells'] array
            $col_max = count($calendar['row_headers']); //each time this column number is reached, we create a new column, the number of cells should divide evenly by the number of row_headers
            foreach($calendar['cells'] as $date => $cell_data ){
                $class = ( !empty($cell_data['events']) && count($cell_data['events']) > 0 ) ? 'eventful':'eventless';
                if(!empty($cell_data['type'])){
                    $class .= "-".$cell_data['type']; 
                }
                ?>
      
            
      <td class="<?php echo $class; ?>">
      <?php if( !empty($cell_data['events']) && count($cell_data['events']) > 0 ): ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url($cell_data['link']); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr($cell_data['link_title']); ?>"><?php echo date('j',$cell_data['date']); ?></a>
                    <?php else:?>
                    <?php echo date('j',$cell_data['date']); ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
      </td>
        
        
        


      
      <?php
                //create a new row once we reach the end of a table column
                $col_count= ($col_count == $col_max ) ? 1 : $col_count+1;
                echo ($col_count == 1 && $count < $cal_count) ? '</tr><tr>':'';
                $count ++; 
            }
            ?>
      
                
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You can do this on the client side with various JS libraries.  Or you can brute force this in PHP with an if block and using the modulus.  If( $rowNumber % 2 ) then it's the 2nd shift, so apply one color.  Then do else's for your other conditions.

Comment: I will give it a try  "if" block using modulus